# How to specify which virtualenv to use in my django project?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I need help to understand how I can:

1) Choose which `virtualenv` my django project should use?

As I understood maybe I'm wrong! when I `activate` the virtualenv, that one my project will be using.

But what about if I'm running on `2 different projects` on a `single server` and each one should use it's own virtualenv?

I'm looking for your help :)

Comment: Can you provide some info about how you're currently launching your django project?

Comment: in development in my local machine: python manage.py runserver --settings=(path to my setting file)

Comment: If you manually switch to the correct venv in command prompt, are you able to launch it like you want?

Comment: Well! that will not help me because I'm planing to deploy 2 projects and I want each one to use it's own venv!

Comment: I was thinking you could make a batch file that looks something like `start C:\path\to\venv\Scripts\bin\python.exe manage.py runserver` or an equivalent shell script if you're on linux/osx

Answer (score 1):

I think this link is very useful. Have a look into it.

[Serving multiple Django applications with Nginx and Gunicorn](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/)

Here, **each application is set up in its own Virtualenv** and each is owned by and run as a different user to limit consequences of a potential security breach.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it .

- Create virtualenv.
- Activate the virtualenv.
- Install Django and other packages in virtualenv.
- python manage.py runserver...

Perhaps is not so much a case of Django using the virtualenv, as the virtualenv using Django.